# Defining a default argument after with None: what if it's an array?

Tags: python, numpy, parameters, arguments

I'm passing an argument to a function such that I want to delay giving the default parameter, in the usual way:

```
def f(x = None):
    if x == None:
        x = ...
```

The only problem is that `x` is likely to be a numpy array. Then `x == None` returns a boolean array, which I can't condition on. The compiler suggests to use `.any()` or `.all()`

But if I write

```
def f(x = None):
    if (x == None).any():
        x = ...
```

this won't work if `x` goes to its default value, because then `None == None` is a Boolean, which has no `.any()` or `.all()` methods. What's my move here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When comparing against **`None`**, it is a good practice to use **`is`** as opposed to `==`.  Usually it doesn't make a difference, but since objects are free to implement equality any way they see fit, it is not always a reliable option.

Unfortunately, this is one of those cases where `==` doesn't cut it, since comparing to numpy arrays returns a boolean mask based on the condition.  Luckily, there is only a single instance of **`None`** in any given Python program, so we can actually check the identity of an object using the **`is`** operator to figure out if it is **`None`** or not.

```
>>> None is None
True    
>>> np.array([1,2,3]) is None
False
```

So no need for **`any`** or **`all`**, you can update your function to something like:

```
def f(x=None):
     if x is None:
         print('None')
     else:
        print('Not none')
```

In action:

```
>>> f()
None
>>> f(np.array([1,2,3]))
Not none
```